# Data Bound RadPanelBar in ASP.NET Not Collapsing

Tags: asp.net, telerik, webforms

I'm binding to a RadPanelBar control using the ItemTemplate; it creates the RadPanelBar correctly using this approach, but the panel bar doesn't close when you click on the header???  How do you get the header click to close the item, or is there an alternative way for this kind of setup?

```
<tel:RadPanelBar ID="r" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" Width="500px"> 
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div> 
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Rel") %>' /> 

      <asp:CheckBoxList ID="fields" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" 
          RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
          DataTextField="RelName" DataSource='<%# Eval("Fields") %>'> 
      </asp:CheckBoxList> 
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate> 
</tel:RadPanelBar>
```

I can't collapse any of the items for some reason.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/panelbar-troubleshooting-root-items-collapse.html) help topic which explains this behavior.